# Google Voice is being sent to gmail's spam

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, google-voice

I'm an admin of a group, the permissions got set to the default team setting for the email group google voice was forwarding to. I have since resolved this to allow anyone on the internet email this group but it then started sending emails from google voice to spam. I was able to search spam and mark them as 'Not Spam' but this only worked for half of the people. I am still having problems with a few accounts sending the google voice email to their spam and do NOT think that creating a filter for each account is an acceptable fix for this issue. Also, I have checked their contacts and google voice's email address is listed in there. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a new filter for these messages if there is some sort of unique identifier in them to match against the filter.  I don't know what you would use off hand, but it could be something in the from, to, or subject fields.  In the actions for the filter, check Never Send to Spam.

Comment: I second filters, they do fantastic things.